# Add and use new ModeLine with nvidia driver

Tags: arch-linux, xorg, nvidia, xrandr

I have a monitor that flickers unless I lower the refresh rate.  With my old ATI card I could use `xrandr` to add a new mode with the max resolution but a slightly lower refresh rate like this

```
xrandr --newmode "1600x1200_59.98" 131.50  1600 1696 1864 2128  1200 1203 1207 1238 -hsync +vsync
xrandr --addmode DVI-D-0        "1600x1200_59.98"
xrandr --output  DVI-D-0 --mode "1600x1200_59.98"
```

But with my new nvidia card I get a BadMatch error on the `--addmode` command.  Allegedly, nvidia doesn't support `xrandr` completely so I must use `nvidia-settings` to generate a xorg.conf file and then edit that to add in the modeline.  So the question now is *why isn't my xorg.conf working?*

This is what was generated by nvidia-settings

```
# ... 
# input stuff
# ...
Section "Monitor" # some other monitor that's not the problem
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Acer H233H"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 770"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-1"
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "HDMI-0: 1920x1080_60 +1600+60, DVI-D-0: 1600x1200_60 +0+0"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

It didn't generate a config for the monitor in question so I added a section, for it with the new ModeLine.  I'm almost positive this is what I've done wrong, because I don't know how to associate this monitor with the actual monitor

```
Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "DVI-D-0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Samsung SyncMaster"
    Option         "DPMS"
    Modeline       "1600x1200_59.98"  161.00  1600 1712 1880 2160  1200 1203 1207 1245 -hsync +vsync
EndSection
```

Then I altered the metamodes section to tell nvidia to use the new "1600x1200_59.98" modeline like so:

```
    Option         "metamodes" "HDMI-0: 1920x1080_60 +1600+60, DVI-D-0: 1600x1200_59.98 +0+0"
```

needless to say, its not working and my samsung monitor is still at 1600x1200_60 according to xrandr.

Comment: what does `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` say about modelines?  if you can see it's finding them but rejecting because non-EDID you may need a Server section `Option "ModeValidation"` override like `AllowNonEdidModes`.  see https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/526093/linux/nvidia-driver-ignores-my-modelines-no-matter-what-i-do/ -- note that post is a few years old, so check the docs on ModeValidation overrides and make sure that advice is still accurate for the current driver.

Comment: It says nothing about adding new modes but it does list attempts to set the mode to the new mode with no errors.  I am currently using `Option "ModeValidation" "AllowNonEdidModes"`.  It doesn't change the behaviour of my `xorg.conf` file _but_ my old `xradr` commands now seem to be working, albeit not reliably enough for me to post about it yet.

Comment: ahh, you might need to bump up the Xserver's logging -- in that link the logs were apparently generated with `startx -- -logverbose 6`.